# IncidentResolution Issue CRM SDK - Value can not be null

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm working on an application which works to anonymise non-production MSCRM environments. My current issue with this is in the process of opening a resolved case (incident), updating and then attempting to resolve the case again. 
Opening and updating bare no issues but since recent updates, my re-closure of these cases no longer works. 
My code is as follows;

```
var incidentResolution = new IncidentResolution
{
    Subject = "Anonymised Incident Resolved",
    IncidentId = new EntityReference(Incident.EntityLogicalName, incId)
};             

var closeIncidentRequest = new CloseIncidentRequest
{
    IncidentResolution = incidentResolution,
    Status = new OptionSetValue(5)                             
};

if (NotifyValidityOfIncidentSolvedStateChange(_orgServ, statusReason, logiName, incId))
{
    try
    {
        _orgServ.Execute(closeIncidentRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = ticket + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from closeIncident request & not from NotifyValidityOfIncidentSolvedStateChange method?

Comment: It is coming from the incidentResolution as when I try to create this through the organisation service, it errors. I placed the _orgServ.Create(incidentResolution); after the incidentResolution block.

Comment: This error may be coming out of a different plugin on closeincident message. Can you check?